# Creating an IFrame using Javascript. Does it block page resources from loading?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

I have a piece of javascript that creates an iframe. The source of the iframe is different than the host domain.

My questions is:

- If the iframe hangs ( server load, failure etc ), do browsers wait on the iframe to load before loading other resources on the page ( images, javascript etc )?
- If that is the case, how can I avoid that, and make the iframe basically non-blocking?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> If the iframe hangs ( server load, failure etc ), do browsers wait on the iframe to load before loading other resources on the page ( images, javascript etc )?

No - frames load separately from the parent page. (This makes your other question irrelevant.)